# Why is my stoplight animation not working?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to make this traffic light to turn on all the lights, but the CSS animation is not working. I have checked numerous times for any missing brackets as well as any other issues.

```css
div {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border: 15px solid rgba(128, 119, 119, 0.877);
  padding: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
}

@keyframes colorOne {
  25% {color: black;}
  50% {color: red;}
  75% {color: black;} 
  100% {color: red;}
}
    
#c1 {
  border: 99px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-name: colorOne;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

@keyframes colorTwo {
  25% {color: black;}
  50% {color: yellow;}
  75% {color: black;}
  100% {color: yellow;}
}
    
#c2 {
  border: 99px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-name: colorTwo;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}
    
@keyframes colorThree {
  25% {color: black;}
  50% {color: green;}
  75% {color: black;}
  100% {color: green;}
}

#c3 {
  border: 99px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-name: colorThree;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="c1"></p>
  <p id="c2" ></p>
  <p id="c3"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome! Please **EDIT** your question with your code, do not post your code as an answer. You will also need to include your HTML, as CSS without HTML is useless to debug. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [create a runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS for each `p` element uses a large border which means that the white colour you can see is the border.
In your animation keyframes declaration `color` sets the color of the text.
Therefore if you change this to `border-color`; it will then start to animate.
Of course I do not know the full extent of the project but you will need to incorporate an [animation delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay) to make it look like a real traffic light or consider another way to control the timings.

Repeat the below for each of the three animations:

```css
@keyframes colorOne {
  0% {
    border-color: black;
  }
  50% {
    border-color: red;
  }
  75% {
    border-color: black;
  }
  100% {
    border-color: red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things to compare and contrast between the CSS in the working example below and the CSS in your question, above.

1. Did you mean for the lights to be upside down (`flex-direction: column-reverse`) or the right way up (`flex-direction: column`) ?
2. If you want to animate the background color of an element, then, conventionally, we give the element a `width` and a `height` and use the `background-color` property.
3. As above, normally, block level elements have a `width` and a `height`. But in a vertical `flexbox` environment, an element will have a `width` and a `flex-basis`. If you want a `flex-basis` (equivalent to a `height` in this instance) to be `198px` and you want this to neither grow nor shrink, you will declare:

   ```
   flex: 0 0 198px;
   ```
4. If you want the final frame of an `animation` to persist, then use `animation-fill-mode: forwards`

---

**Working Example:**

```css
div {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border: 15px solid rgba(128, 119, 119, 0.877);
  padding: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
}

@keyframes colorOne { 
  25% {background-color: black;}
  50% {background-color: red;}
  75% {background-color: black;}
  100% {background-color: red;}
}
    
#c1 {
  flex: 0 0 198px;
  width: 198px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: colorOne 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes colorTwo {
  25% {background-color: black;}
  50% {background-color: yellow;}
  75% {background-color: black;}
  100% {background-color: yellow;}
}
    
#c2 {
  flex: 0 0 198px;
  width: 198px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: colorTwo 5s linear forwards;
}
    
@keyframes colorThree {
  25% {background-color: black;}
  50% {background-color: green;}
  75% {background-color: black;}
  100% {background-color: green;}
}

#c3 {
  flex: 0 0 198px;
  width: 198px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: colorThree 5s linear forwards;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="c1"></p>
  <p id="c2" ></p>
  <p id="c3"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a great answer but might I suggest a grid and let the orb content size determine the width/height given some padding on the container and between the orbs as a gap.  Note I changed from a paragraph to a div to make that gap work best/better here.

Using a grid like I have for the BODY and orb container "super-centers" the element/grid contents easily.

Give the orbs a class to make it more DRY, then just put the "color" on each (I used a class for clarity rather than the IDs)

As an addition I put color variables in place for the background of each and added a border to show the use of that can be for the orb size and not all this huge bordering you had.

Try changing the orb size from `8em` and see how it adjusts.

```css
body,
* {
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  --orb-red: #FF0000;
  --orb-yellow: #FFFF00;
  --orb-green: #008000;
  --orb-off: #000000;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.light-container {
  background-color: #000000;
  border: 1em solid rgba(128, 119, 119, 0.877);
  padding: 2em;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  gap: 0.5em;
}

.light-orb {
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  width: 8em;
  height: 8em;
  margin: 1em;
  border: solid 0.25em #ffffff;
}

@keyframes colorOne {
  25% {
    background-color: var(--orb-off);
  }
  50% {
    background-color: var(--orb-red);
  }
  75% {
    background-color: var(--orb-off);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: var(--orb-red);
  }
}

@keyframes colorTwo {
  25% {
    background-color: var(--orb-off);
  }
  50% {
    background-color: var(--orb-yellow);
  }
  75% {
    background-color: var(--orb-off);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: var(--orb-yellow);
  }
}

@keyframes colorThree {
  25% {
    background-color: var(--orb-off);
  }
  50% {
    background-color: var(--orb-green);
  }
  75% {
    background-color: var(--orb-off);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: var(--orb-green);
  }
}

.top-light {
  animation-name: colorOne;
}

.middle-light {
  animation-name: colorTwo;
}

.bottom-light {
  animation-name: colorThree;
}
```

```html
<div class="light-container">
  <div class="light-orb top-light" id="c1"></div>
  <div class="light-orb middle-light" id="c2"></div>
  <div class="light-orb bottom-light" id="c3"></div>
</div>
```